# Reading Numbers in a Text file line by line and running them through a small comparison script using python csv

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and I am trying to import a txt file, read it line by line ( each line only contains numbers) and the file looks like:

```
350
490
700
10
59
2000
```

So far I have :

```
import sys
import csv

with open("file.txt") as f:

        c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        line = []
        for line in c:
                print(line)
        if line > 300 and line < 500:
                print "a"
        elif line > 501 and line < 701:
                print "b"
        else:
                print "c"
```

Although this reads every line but it fails to execute the if statement and only prints "c" . I am wondering how I can fix this issue. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Debugging is easier when also printing the type of a certain variable. So next time add `print(type(line))` and add `print(line > 300)` and you'll be able to solve this puzzle for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an indenting issue, also as has been mentioned, the `csv` module treats all entries in your file as strings, as such you first need to convert each entry into an integer using the `int` command as follows:

```
import sys
import csv

with open("file.txt") as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

    for line in c:
        print line
        value = int(line[0])  # convert the first column to an integer (in case there are more than 1)

        if 300 < value < 500:
            print "a"
        elif 501 < value < 701:
            print "b"
        else:
            print "c"
```

For your example, this would then display the following output:

```
['350']
a
['490']
a
['700']
b
['10']
c
['59']
c
['2000']
c
```

Note, your code would print `c` for a value of 500. If you wanted to include it with `a` you would need to use `<= 500`.

Answer (score 2):

When you read data from a file, the values are strings. If you want to treat them as numbers, you need to convert the data first. For example:

```
n = int(line)

if n > 300 and n < 500:
    # etc...
```

In addition, the structure of your program is a bit unusual, because the conditional logic is completely outside the line-by-line processing. A more typical approach would be to iterate over the data yielded by the CSV reader, performing conditional logic on each line. Also note that the reader returns a list of values (or fields, as they are often called when dealing with CSV files). Here's an illustration:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
for fields in reader:
    val = int(fields[0])
    if val > 300 and val < 500:
        print 'a'
    elif val > 501 and val < 701:
        print 'b'
    else:
        print 'c'
```

Comment: You don't need to `strip()` to convert to `int`, `int(line)` suffices.

Comment: ok so I have done as you guys suggested and made sure the file is now 'int' format but I still get the same issue :                                                                         f = open("happy.txt")
for line in f:                                  
    n = int(line.strip())
    print type(n)
    print n
if n > 300 and n < 500:
        print "a"
elif n > 501 and n < 701:
        print "b"
else:
        print "c"

Comment: <type 'int'>
305
<type 'int'>
237
<type 'int'>
309
<type 'int'>
7878
<type 'int'>
123
c

Comment: Ok now it works, I just used n = int(line.strip()) and it works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert text from file into integers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11094505)

Comment: @MartinEvans it is not critique - it is answer. OP has to convert every `line` from file into integer - `int(line)`.